# Python pattern for read-only attributes in a typed context

Tags: python, mypy, private-members

Our code is quite strict in separating private, protected, and public attributes of our Python objects, following the convention that private attributes start with `__` (and are thus mangled to include the class name), protected attributes start with `_` and public attributes don't start with `_`.

However, a frequent pattern we have is wanting to expose an attribute as privately writable, but publically readable, and subject to static type annotations. This is further complicated by the fact that we extensively use the `override` package to typecheck the methods of subclasses.

Our code is thus littered with

```
class C:
    self.__attribute: T

    def __init__(self, attribute: T):
        self.__attribute = attribute

    @property
    def attribute(self) -> T:
        return self.attribute
```

in place of what could be simple data classes.

Is there a good pattern to minimize the boilerplate? What about

```
class B(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def weird_attribute(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class D(B):
    self.__weird_attribute: T

    def __init__(self, wattribute: T):
        self.__weird_attribute = wattribute

    @property  # type: ignore
    @overrides
    def weird_attribute(self) -> T:
        return self.__weird_attribute

class E(B):
    @property  # type: ignore
    @overrides
    def weird_attribute(self) -> T:
        return 1
```

This style really bugs me, because we try to use static type checking to have a good grasp of our code – and then this bad pattern requires a `# type: ignore` because properties cannot be decorated and overrides cannot be properties. And it's not even concise.

Is there a way out?

Comment: Have you considered writing your own linter rule to enforce the convention rather than trying to use the type system (which doesn’t natively support that type of distinction)?  Linters already exist to enforce the “protected attribute” convention, it seems like you should be able to write something that enforces the system you describe.

Comment: That sounds like a sensible suggestion which would never have crossed my mind! I'll see whether that could work.

Answer (score -1):

As of Python 3.10, this easy using [data classes](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/dataclasses.html#descriptor-typed-fields) and [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors):

```py
import dataclasses
from typing import cast, Generic, TypeVar


_T = TypeVar('_T')


class Prop(Generic[_T]):
    _name: str
    _mangeled_name: str

    def __set_name__(self, owner: type, name: str) -> None:
        self._name = name
        self._mangeled_name = f'_{owner.__name__}__{name}'

    def __get__(self, instance: object | None, owner: type) -> _T:
        if instance is not None:
            try:
                return cast(_T, getattr(instance, self._mangeled_name))
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        raise AttributeError(self._name)

    def __set__(self, instance: object, value: _T) -> None:
        if hasattr(instance, self._mangeled_name):
            raise AttributeError(f"can't set attribute {self._name!r}")
        setattr(instance, self._mangeled_name, value)


@dataclasses.dataclass
class C:
    attribute: Prop[str] = Prop()
```

The setter allows a single assignment to the attribute, which will occur in the `__init__()` method generated by the `dataclasses()` decorator.

`reveal_type(C.attribute)` reveals the type as `str` and `attribute` will be required in the constructor.

Or skip the data classes and use the example below if any of the following apply:

- An earlier version of Python is in use (without appropriate data class support)
- You would rather not use data classes
- The type of the attribute should be decided by what is passed into the constructor

```py
class C(Generic[_T]):
    attribute: Prop[_T] = Prop()

    def __init__(self, attribute: _T) -> None:
        self.attribute = attribute
```

You can also decrease boilerplate code by writing your own data classes-like decorator:

```py
def propclass(cls: type[_T]) -> type[_T]:
    for name in cls.__init__.__annotations__:
        prop: Prop[_T] = Prop()
        setattr(cls, name, prop)
        prop.__set_name__(cls, name)
    return cls


@propclass
class C(Generic[_T]):
    def __init__(self, attribute: _T) -> None:
        self.attribute: _T = attribute
```

This is even compatible with data classes:

```py
@propclass
@dataclasses.dataclass
class C:
    attribute: int
```

And take it a step further by applying the `dataclass` decorator in the `propclass` decorator so that only one decorator is required:

```py
def propclass(cls: type[_T]) -> type[_T]:
    cls = dataclasses.dataclass(cls)
    ...

@propclass
class C:
    attribute: float
```

Tested with Python 3.10.9 and mypy 1.0.1.

Comment: Two issues in my IDE (Pycharm): 1. I get warning in constructor when trying to pass string, `Expected type 'Prop[str]', got 'str' instead`, 2. Typing `in.attribute.` doesn't autocomplete string methods. Meaning that Pycharm doesn't recognize `attribute` as a `str` type, regardless of `reveal_type` -- which BTW is Python 3.11+ *only*.

Comment: @rv.kvetch I'm using PyCharm 2022.3.3 Professional and autocomplete works great and there are no type errors. The data class support is a newer feature that is likely not supported in older versions of PyCharm. Try upgrading. BTW, I was referring to Mypy's [`reveal_type`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#reveal-type), a type annotation debugging feature that's been around for at least 7 years.